# Is there any software to program accompaniment quickly without electronic keyboard?

Tags: chords, software

Is there any software where I can select a style and mention the chord names to be played?

I used to do it with my yamaha keyboard where I could select a nice style and create chord progressions but I fried my keyboard and I am waiting for a new one.

I want a software where I can select a style like pop ballad or rock and add the chords to be played. And I can listen to it just by hitting play and then edit the style and chords just by mentioning it's name and not by adding every single key of the chord.

Thanks.

Comment: Finale series programs can do it with "Band in a Box" if you have a score.  I think others can do it too. But this looks like a software recommendation to me, and those are off topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [Band-in-a-Box](http://www.pgmusic.com). It is extremely rich and powerful for generating accompaniment tracks.

If you are on Android tablet, iPad or iPhone or Mac OS X, there is also [iReal Pro](http://irealpro.com). It is very simple to use, but its results are not as good as those created by Band-in-a-Box. iReal Pro also has thousands of song charts of jazz and pop standards available for downloading from their website after you purchase the program.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Chorrdbot](https://chordbot.com/install/) application for Android and Iphones. It is simple to use. It allows the user to customize the style. It can export the chord sequence as MIDI format as well as WAV format which you can import to garage band.

Answer (score 0):

Any reasonable digital audio workbench should allow you to input notes with a computer keyboard and mouse.

Assuming I didn't misinterpret your question completely, I could probably set up something like that in GarageBand with minimal effort.